# Naive Grouping for Factorization

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization, hyperbolic-functions, integer-lattices

I have a naive grouping method for factorization.  I am curious as to its novelty and aspects of the code below that will increase its efficiency.

The method is best described with an example:

For ***n = 798,607*** if we start with a seed group of ***59***, we would have ***17*** groups of ***13,535*** and ***42*** groups of ***13,536***.  Neither the ***17*** nor the ***42*** will evenly parse the other grouping totals so we double the seed group.  Now we have ***118*** groups in total, ***17*** groups of ***6,767*** and ***101*** groups of ***6,768***.  The ***6,767*** can be distributed among the ***101*** groups, resulting in factors of ***101*** groups of ***7,907***.

I have found that all seed groups are odd and less than $\sqrt n \over 2$ and there exist multiple (unknown quantity) seed groups yielding factors.  The seed groups (***i***) are only expanded until the groups are greater than the group counts, or the initial seed group splits do not carry forward (i.e., ***17***  or ***42*** groups from seed group ***59*** needs to be a solution in the ***118*** groups split.)

```
#Naive Grouping
NaiveGrouping <- function(number){

  r<- as.integer(sqrt(number)/2)
  i<-3

while(i<=r){
  for (j in 0:(floor(log2(number)))){   


  Seed_Group<-(i*(2^j))

  Counts <- (number/Seed_Group)

  if(Counts%%1==0){
            return(c(Seed_Group=Seed_Group,End_Group=Seed_Group,Factors=Seed_Group,number/Seed_Group))
         }


  count_ceiling <- (ceiling(Counts))
  count_floor <- (floor(Counts))

  initial_group_ceiling <- (number%%i)
  initial_group_floor <- (i - number%%i) 

  group_ceiling <- number%%Seed_Group
  group_floor <- (Seed_Group - (group_ceiling))

      if(group_floor==initial_group_floor | group_ceiling==initial_group_ceiling)    
      if(group_floor==1 | group_ceiling==1) next
      if(group_floor>count_ceiling | group_ceiling>count_floor) break


      if(count_floor%%group_ceiling==0){
               return(matrix(c(group_floor,count_floor,group_ceiling,count_ceiling,i,group_floor+group_ceiling,group_ceiling,number/group_ceiling),4,2,byrow=TRUE,dimnames=list(c("Group Floor","Group Ceiling", "Seed Group, End Group","Factors"),c("Groups","Counts")))) 

              }

      if(count_ceiling%%group_floor==0){
               return(matrix(c(group_floor,count_floor,group_ceiling,count_ceiling,i,group_floor+group_ceiling,group_floor,number/group_floor),4,2,byrow=TRUE,dimnames=list(c("Group Floor","Group Ceiling", "Seed Group, End Group","Factors"),c("Groups","Counts"))))

              }
      }
  i=i+2L
  }
return("Prime")
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have discovered a new relationship between the Naive Grouping method above and lattice points on a hyperbola which solve for factors of ***N***.

Using the code provided the result for $N=7,084,149,637$ is:

```
> (NaiveGrouping(7084149637)) 
                         Groups Counts 
Group Floor                2795 82781 
Group Ceiling             82781 82782 
Seed Group, End Group     10697 85576 
Factors                   82781 85577
```

The Group Floor (***2795***) is related to a polynomial of the form $N -x^2 - yx - x = 0$. When $y=2795$ , upon examination of the polynomial and the resulting hyperbola, the only lattice points not containing ***1*** or ***N*** occur with the factors of ***N*** for $y=2795 , -2797$.

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7084149637+-x%5E2+-yx+-x+%3D0) is the Wolfram Alpha link to this example.  Try other ***N*** to see how this holds for other factorizations.

***2795*** is the Group Floor within the End Group ***85,576***. I achieved this from expanding the Seed Group ***10,697***. However, if I had tested the Seed Group to see whether it generates an integer solution to the polynomial, I would have stopped with a result after just ***~ 1,400*** steps since the y-coordinates are only odd.

I have updated the algorithm to search for integer solutions to the polynomial at every Seed Group using Newton's Method (detailed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347331/newton-raphson-for-integer-factorization)), however, the relationship does not hold for every ***N***. In those instances, the Naive Grouping will return the factors first as the associated y-coordinates are greater than $\sqrt n \over 2$ range required.  Expanding the Seed Group for y-coordinate tests via multiplication at every iteration reconciles the range issue.  So, it seems to be a probabilistic accompaniment to the deterministic Naive Grouping method.

I would like to know more about lattice points on hyperbolas related to factorization.  Particularly if these points have a general range or maximum value relative to ***N***.  Also, how Wolfram Alpha determines them so quickly! If anyone has any insights as to why this is occurring or suggestions of related literature please feel free to comment.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I don't get how you choose to divide $59$ in $42$ and $17$, that seems arbitrary. Moreover, it would be helpful if you could provide pseudocode for your method: this would make it easier for mathematicians who know factorization but do not read code well to help you.

Comment: Thanks!  A smaller example might illustrate better.  For ***n=49***, if I initially split it into 2 groups, I would have 1 group of ***25*** and 1 group of ***24***.  If I split each of those groups into 2, the ***25*** would be split into ***13*** and ***12***, and the ***24*** would be split into ***12*** and ***12***.  Splitting all of those groups into 2 (hence the "Naive" description), I would be left with ***7*** groups of ***6*** and ***1*** group of ***7***.  The single group of ***7*** can be placed in the ***7*** groups of ***6***, yielding factors ***7*** and ***7***.

Comment: I ran out of characters.  My other point is that each group count has a difference of 1, in essence trying to get the most even distribution (again, "Naive") from the seed group.  ***17*** and ***42*** are the only two groups that will yield a total of ***59*** under that distribution constraint.